# DI compile step fails after update to 2.3.5

Tags: upgrade, setup-di-compile

Using Magento Cloud, the DI compile step keeps failing after upgrading from 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 via composer and pushing the changes up.

The error is the same every time I've tried, which is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\NodeList::item($index) : ?Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\ElementInterface must be compatible with Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\NodeListInterface::item(int $index): ?Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\ElementInterface in /app/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php on line 19
```

The only difference in declaration seems to be the "int" type declared for the $index parameter in the adapter interface. But both of the referenced files seem to exist in the same composer package (magento/module-page-builder) so I am a bit confused about how to solve it.

The version of module-page-builder that composer installed is 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only difference in declaration seems to be the "int" type declared for the $index parameter

This is the main problem. Method declaration should be the same as in the interface

As I can see 1.3.1 is the latest version, so you can create a patch for fixing the issue in vendor modules.

add patch to composer.json

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "enable-patching": true,
        "patches": 
            "magento/module-page-builder": {
                "Declaration fix": {
                    "1.3.1": "patches/PageBuilder/1.3.1/fix_revert.patch"
                }
            },
```

and create patch under `patches/PageBuilder/1.3.1/fix_revert.patch` by adding `int` into declaration and using `git diff`

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea! I will just patch it for now.

Comment: This worked! For the record, I needed to `cd vendor/magento/module-page-builder`, run `git init` to create a blank repo for the module, commit the original code, make my fix, and then I could use `git diff` to create the patch file. I then deleted my new .git directory to clean up, and applied the patch with composer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue can you please simplify how to use it?

Answer (score 6):

Please verify your PHP version. I encountered the same issue while on PHP 7.1. Switching to PHP 7.2 resolved this error.

Good luck!